# Bootstrap 4 carousel, show 3. Advance 1

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I found this carousel and I am not sure how to make it work with the newest bootstrap 4.

https://www.codeply.com/go/FrzoIEKCdH/bootstrap-4-carousel-multiple

```js
< script >
  $('#recipeCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 10000
  })

  <
  /script>
```

```css
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
  transform: translateX(33.33%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  transform: translateX(-33.33%)
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container text-center my-3">
  <h2>Bootstrap 4 Multiple Item Carousel</h2>
  <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
    <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block col-4 img-fluid" src="images/Action%201.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block col-4 img-fluid" src="images/Action%202.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block col-4 img-fluid" src="images/Action%203.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h4>Advances one slide at a time</h4>
</div>
```

Again, this is NOT working with the newest bootstrap, it works on that link. Because that link is using bootstrap 4.0. The newest is just shows 1 image on the left at a time.

Comment: Any help guys??

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy all of the JavaScript from that example? Seems like you're missing the following:

```
$('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function(){
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
    else {
      $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```